# ERROR Fatal error: Illegal or unknown default time zone 'UTC'

Tags: mysql

I am running MySQL 5.1 from package on Mac OSX 10.6.
I am trying running: sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --skip-grant --user root --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data

This error is preventing me from starting the database and importing the timezone information or doing anything else. I've tried clean installing with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Named timezones are usable when they exist in your mysql database.
In your case it seems that you don't have them there, so you can use offset relatives to UTC e.g: '+07:00' or '-04:00' or '+00:00'.

Comment: This does not work when timezone change during the year for summertime like "Europe/Paris" or "Europe/Rome"

Comment: @balucio Yes, and it's best to install correct timezones and use them instead to avoid such issues

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `Etc/UTC`. Correct the relevant setting in your MySQL config.